# How to fix a function that isn't calling (No error alerts)

Tags: vb.net, function

This is some code for my Computing coursework to create a seat booking system allowing a user to input a desired row and the number of adjacent seats required, and then the form outputs a message showing what seats are available or an alert if there is not enough seats in that row.

The main problem I am having is that I have no errors, but once the submit button is clicked nothing happens which would suggest the "seatsBlock" function is not calling, and I was wondering if anyone could give me a solution

```
Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim rowNumber As Integer

        If ListBox2.Text = "A" Then
            rowNumber = 1
        ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "B" Then
            rowNumber = 2
        ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "C" Then
            rowNumber = 3
        ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "D" Then
            rowNumber = 4
        ElseIf ListBox2.Text = "E" Then
            rowNumber = 5
        End If

        SearchSeats(rowNumber, ListBox1.Text)

    End Sub
    Function SearchSeats(ByVal RowNumber As Integer, ByVal NumSeats As Integer) As String
        Dim CountSeat As Integer = 0 '
        Dim FirstSeat As String = 0
        Dim lastSeat As String = 0

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        FirstSeat = SeatsBlock(RowNumber, i, FirstSeat, lastSeat)
        Do While NumSeats > CountSeat
            If i > 9 Then
                Return ("There are not enough seats available in this block")
                Exit Do
            End If
            If SeatsBlock(RowNumber, i, FirstSeat, lastSeat) = "booked" Then
                CountSeat = 0
                FirstSeat = SeatsBlock(RowNumber, (i + 1), FirstSeat, lastSeat)
            Else
                lastSeat = SeatsBlock(RowNumber, i, FirstSeat, lastSeat)
                CountSeat = i + 1
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Return ("There are currently " & NumSeats & "seats available: " & FirstSeat & " - " & lastSeat)

    End Function
    Function SeatsBlock(ByVal RowNumber As Integer, ByVal NumSeats As Integer, ByVal FirstSeat As String, ByVal LastSeat As String) As String
        Return ("Currently available are " & NumSeats & " seats available: " & FirstSeat & " - " & LastSeat)
    End Function



    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Dim SeatsBlock As String(,) = {{"A1", "A2", "booked", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "booked", "A10"}, {"booked", "booked", "booked", "B4", "B5", "booked", "booked", "B8", "booked", "B10"}, {"C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5", "C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10"}, {"D1", "booked", "booked", "D4", "D5", "D6", "D7", "D8", "D9", "D10"}, {"E1", "E2", "booked", "booked", "booked", "E6", "E7", "E8", "E9", "E10"}}
    End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you reach a breakpoint when debugging on the Button1_Click event? Meaning does it reach the function at all?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
    SearchSeats(rowNumber, ListBox1.Text)
```

for this:

```
    Msgbox(SearchSeats(rowNumber, ListBox1.Text))
```

That way you get a messagebox, else you will never see the error!